# How to add a rectangular overlay over camera and save image to gallery using flutter

Tags: flutter, camera, overlay, flutter-layout

I need to add the overlay above the camera like rectangle box and need to save the image to gallery

Tried the basic flutter camera example[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozrbP.jpg)

Comment: if you tried the basic example, whats your code then?

Comment: I have just cloned the project from https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/camera .I dont know how to add the overlay above thiis

Answer (score -1):

If you are not too worried about limiting the image resolution to the phone's display resolution, you can opt to automatically take a screenshot of the display and save it.

For this to work, you'll need Flutter [native_screenshot](https://pub.dev/packages/native_screenshot) package.

1. Capturing the screenshot:

```
  Future<void> takeScreenShot() async{
    String path = await NativeScreenshot.takeScreenshot();
    print(path);
  }
```

The image will be saved in the folder indicated by the `path`.

2. Since the function captures the whole screen, you can use a `Stack()` widget to display your camera preview and the overlay on top of each other. A simple `build` would look like,

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (controller == null || !controller.value.isInitialized) {
      return Container();
    }

    return OverflowBox(
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          CameraPreview(controller),
          Container(),
    
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

In the above code you'll need to initialize the camera controller in order to display the `CamerarPreview()`. You can edit the `Container()` child widget (or anything similar to that) to create your overlay box.